# How does retaining a UIView work with ARC in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, automatic-ref-counting

I am creating my custom `UIViewController` subclass.

I add `UIView *menuView;` into the class definition.

I create this view earlier (not lazily) while initializing the class.

After a while, when it is necessary I will add it to current view and remove it again to be able to add it again...

Since these does not happen in the same loop/cycle, ARC will release `menuView`. As I can't manually retain and as I don't want to use `@property(nonatomic,retain)` (as this view is private), how should this scenario work? How to keep that `UIView` without adding it to a parent view?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `@property (nonatomic, retain)` in your .m file like this:

```
@interface myViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *myView;
@end

@implementation myViewController
@synthesize ...
-(id)init...
...
```

This way it stays private.
Notice the two parenthesis used in interface implementation in .m file.

Comment: Does this mean that there are no other ways other than using these automatic properties?